# using tcpdf in zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2, tcpdf

my composer.json file look like this

```
.....
"require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "2.5.1",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "0.7.*",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "zendframework/zftool": "dev-master",
        "tecnickcom/tcpdf"            : "dev-master"
    }...
```

and now updating composer updaing the tcpdf directory and download all the files but i am unable to create new instance by `new tcpdf();` or with `new \tcpdf();`
the error says

```
 Class '\tcpdf' not found in S:\xampp...
```

Comment: Did you add this `use \TCPDF;` in your file??

Comment: isn't it the same thing

Comment: I think you need to try..

Comment: check out this : https://github.com/tawfekov/ZF2-Tcpdf/blob/master/Module.php#L7